# iOS Hidding status bar on a modal view

Tags: ios, iphone, statusbar, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm trying to display a full image on screen, by pushing a modal view, with the full image, i managed to do that with no problem, but for some reason i cannot hide the status bar on the modal, i'm presenting the modal from a `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` of a collection view, i'm trying to hide the status bar, before calling the `presentViewController`, here's the code:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSArray *infoPhoto = self.imagesFromCD[indexPath.row];

   // NSLog(@"Info photos = %@", infoPhoto);
    NSString *imageName = [[self.imagesFromCD valueForKey:@"imgNameCD"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *imageToPass = [self getImageFromDocuments:imageName];

    displayImageViewController *displayVC = [[displayImageViewController alloc]init]; 
    displayVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
    displayVC.transitioningDelegate = self;
    displayVC.foto = infoPhoto;
    displayVC.imageToDisplay = imageToPass;

    UIApplication *myapp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [myapp setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:YES]; // Heres where the bar should be hidden.
    [self presentViewController:displayVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I also tried to add the:

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Inside the Modal .m file, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

First of all set in your `info.plist` View controller-based status bar appearance is equal to no and than use below where ever you want to status bar hidden or not:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                        withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO
                                        withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```